# TCL: How to convert a tcl data into json format?

Tags: arrays, json, tcl

For an example tcl array:

```
set arr {"key" {1 2 3}}
```

conversion into json format

```
{"key" : [1,2,3]}
```

I am looking for a solution for above example without using any library.

Comment: That'd be hard I think... but are you able to put the module in form of a tcl file and source it?

Comment: One of the reasons it's difficult with Tcl data: how do you tell the difference between `"a string with spaces"` and `{a list of strings}`?

Comment: Here arr is the dict of list in tcl

Comment: If every element of array is a string key and a value that is a list of numbers, you could use (for instance) `dict for {key val} $arr {puts [subst [format {{"%s" : \[[join {%s} ,]]}} $key $val]]} `. But if there is the slightest variation in type (as perceived by JSON), say `{123 {Hello, world!}}`, you get munged JSON. If you are going to convert to JSON and be reasonably sure what you are getting, you need type-tagged data on the Tcl side (such as `{{S name} {A {N 1} {N 2} {N 3}}}` or an existing type-tagging format like `huddle`).

Comment: I know you don’t want to use any module, but e.g. `huddle` can really give you a hand here. If your array looks like `set arr {name {1 2 3} foo {4 5 6}}` then `huddle jsondump [huddle compile {dict * list} $arr]` will give you `{ "name": [ 1, 2, 3 ], "foo": [ 4, 5, 6 ] }` (whitespace-edited), and if you happen to set the dictionary to `set arr {name {1 2 3} foo {hello, world!}} ` you will at least get valid JSON: `{ "name": [ 1, 2, 3 ], "foo": [ "hello,", "world!" ] }`. (cont.)

Comment: (cont’d) Type negotiation isn’t trivial (except when it is), so a good module will be helpful. Of course, using `json::write` will cut out the middleman: `dict for {key val} $arr {puts [json::write object $key [json::write array {*}$val]]}` gives `{ "name" : [1,2,3] }` and `{ "foo" : [4,5,6] }`, but works only for the correct type combination (`{ "foo" : [hello,,world!] }`, hmm).

Comment: @Peter,  compile_json {spec data } @ https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/13419 is working for me. But I want to give only data as input argument . It is easy for me to determine spec of simple data like list , string or dict etc.                        How to determine spec for data   like {a {{c 1} {d {2 2 2} e 3}} b {{f 4 g 5}}} ?

Comment: I am not really famiiliar with `compile_json` but it seems that the source of the command together with the `huddle compile` docs should enable you to experiment your way to a spec. The string representation of the data itself does not reliably suggest a spec. While one could make guesses about a data string like `{a {{c 1} {d {2 2 2} e 3}} b {{f 4 g 5}}}`, only the semantics you have in mind will reliably tell which parts are strings, lists, etc.

Comment: Donal Fellows reminded me that there is also https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json nowadays,  not "standard" but apparently highly recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be difficult and convoluted to do on your own due to ambiguities in the language like lists vs strings with spaces, or the fact that numbers are strings in Tcl. However, at least two great libraries exist to handle this and make the process much more readable:

- One option is [rl_json](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json) which defines a new object type for JSON and adds the `json` command with intuitive subcommands.
- Another option is [yajl-tcl](https://github.com/flightaware/yajl-tcl) which is an interface for the C [yajl](https://github.com/lloyd/yajl) library. yajl-tcl works more like building JSON line-by-line, which might not be as intuitive as rl_json but works well nonetheless.